# Dynamic Drop down menu appearing in relation to browser window's width

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

I wanna implement an icon which when clicked will make appear a menu right below the icon. Now, the horizontal position of the icon may vary with different browser window width, but I want the menu to appear exactly below the icon, and not messing my entire page layout(but just appearing above whatever is in that position), and when the user clicks elsewhere on the screen the menu will disappear. And in case the menu is open and the window is being resized, the menu shall move as well(and not mess the layout), remaining under the icon.
 Any ideas on how to implement such drop down menu?
 Or at least what are the js and css tools I need to know in order to implement this?

Comment: Have you written *any* code yet ? Can you please show us ? Tools you need : html and css, not necessarily js.

Comment: Look into node.offsetLeft

Comment: Welcome to SO. Looks like you need to do some more research. StackOverflow is more for asking questions if you get stuck on a specific problem. Show the code that you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get the position of an element:

```
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;

    while (element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}
```

Used like this:

```
var pos = getPosition(element);
var x = pos["x"];
var y = pos["y"];
```

You will want to base the menu's position on the position of the icon when it is first created and when the browser is resized: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  //set position here
});
```

To make the menu not effect any other elements on the page you can set `position: absolute` and append it to the body. You might also have to set the `z-index` to some high value as well depending on the other elements on your page

You can probably also implement this with just html and css, though javascript may be supported by more browsers, not sure. But a css solution might be worth looking in to as well, look for pseudo elements